# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError Even when you have class existed in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am facing NoClassDefFoundError for support lib files in Android studio even when files are there in project. I am thinking its coming because of support lib. I think i have properly included support libs in project. This is how i have added.

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            name 'maven.aviary.com'
            url uri("http://maven.aviary.com/repo/release")
        }
    }

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 21
        buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.path"
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 21
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            multiDexEnabled = true
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled true
                shrinkResources true
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
            debug {
                debuggable true
            }
        }
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        }
        dexOptions {
            jumboMode true
            javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.3'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
        compile project(':Aviary-SDK')
        compile project(':facebook')
    }
```

Error:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.path.SocialNetworkManager at

com.path.fragments.SocialNetworkFragment.onCreateView(SocialNetworkFragment.j

ava:120)android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)

Still i am getting error. I am using Support lib version V4 in Facebook and Aviary SDk  and my project too,is this error coming because of this? if yes how to solve this issue , how to separate same lib for different modules in android studio.

please help me

Comment: You should check export in build settings for only one of those if you don't have already support lib in main project, otherwise uncheck in both.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do that(Uncheck libs) .. i am new to Android studio and Gradle build system.

Comment: Right click, go to project Properties > Java Build Path > Order and Export

Comment: The error message doesn't look like it's related to support lib. It's in the `com.path` package, not `com.android.support`.